# Does "increasingly larger" imply an increasing rate of growth?

Tags: adjectives, compounds

We often say things become "increasingly larger/bigger", like "The problem of [...] is becoming an increasingly larger issue". I was wondering if the addition of the word "increasingly" is simply used to stress the growth, or if it implies that the rate of growth itself is also increasing (exponentially, for instance).

Insights both in terms of colloquial usage and more technical, precise usage would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Increasingly" is added to convey the idea of ongoing process.

> [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/increasingly?q=increasingly)) **increasingly** more and more all the time

If you don't use this adverb, for example in "The problem …", then you get the idea that  the problem, from a given state of difficulty is becoming a problem that will show to have a certain more or less predictable level of difficulty;

- The problem of [...] is becoming a larger issue (*numerous examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22becoming%20a%20larger%20issue%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)*)

the use of the adverb does awway with this idea, and all that is said is that the degree of difficulty will always increase. Of course, there is a limit that is more or less evident sometimes, but the assertion is not concerned with it and considers the question independently, that is, on the period of time that this limit defines.

There is no difference whether the use of this phrase concerns scientific language or not. The rate of growth is not specified in any way, and therefore it  can be constant as well.